# Dataset for emotion classification on social media

Tags: text, machine-learning, social-networking

I would like to do emotion classification on text (posts from social media e.g. tweets, facebook wall posts, youtube comments etc ...). Though I can't find a **good dataset with annotated data**. I'm looking for more than just data annotated with positive and negative. I'm looking for a dataset with several emotions. This could be or discrete values (ekman 6 basic emotions) or continues values (arousal-valence model). Does anyone know where I can get such a dataset, this can be from twitter, Facebook, Myspace ... as long it is from a social network

Answer (score 1):

well, I think better name (or, more often used) would be **Sentiment analysis** (Sentiment classification) - correct? I'm not sure if social media do offer their private data (maybe some part of it). Anyway, I found this paper:

http://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/llee/papers/sentiment.pdf

They are dealing with data: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/pabo/movie-review-data/ from https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!aboutgroup/rec.arts.movies.reviews.

Does it suit you? Basically, finding appropriate data is usually a big problem in ML. Often it is needed to build your own (I mean to classify a part of it manually and apply some clustering or semi-supervised learning afterwards)

If you don't find anything appropriate on the web, I'd try to contact some authors that write articles similar to your research. Maybe they will have already created datasets that will fit you...

Comment: Sentiment analysis generally is determining if the text if positive or negative, which is not the same as what I'm looking for. Though I found what I was looking for by contacting an author.

Comment: @Ojtwist: you wrote:" I'm looking for a dataset with several emotions. " I think it is still classification (even one example has multiple labels)

Comment: can you give me the the dataset that the professor gave you? Because I need it.